# How can i launch ubuntu staright away

Tags: boot, 15.04

I have dual booted windows and ubuntu, and for the past two days whenever I launch my laptop it goes straight into windows and I have to open ubuntu through the windows boot menu, its probably really obvious but I am still fairly new to ubuntu and would appreciate any help, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Install [Grub Customizer](https://launchpad.net/grub-customizer) and check your settings. Maybe it's set to [automatically boot the previously booted system](http://postimg.org/image/rmaaswoan/), or GRUB is only visible for a short time.

Comment: Thanks did not think i would get an answer

Comment: This did not work but i did solve the problem by going into system setup then into the boot options and putting ubuntu above windows on the boot list for anyone having similar problems